# String split in java

Tags: android

I have `String` like:

`Start:Monday, August 15, 2011 8:00am (Eastern Standard Time)End:Monday, August 15, 2011 9:00am (Eastern Standard Time)Where:Who:Description:`

I want to split it like this:

```
Start : (newline)
End:    (newline)
Where:  (newline) 
Who:    (newline)
Description: (newline)
```

Mind that `:` after start and each tag value change it dynamically, so please give me a  dynamical solution

Comment: Could your show what you've tried so far. We're not code monkeys, we're here to help

Comment: Will you have the tags same for each time such as Start: End: ?

Comment: I guess you need to write you own method to parse the String. Do you have an option to use a special character as a marker/separator? Then you could easily split your String with `String.split("separator")`

Answer (score 1):

By using the below code you can get your string like:

> Start:Monday, August 15, 2011 8-00am (Eastern Standard Time)End:Monday, August 15, 2011 9-00am

then you can use String.split("separator")

```
String strTest="Start:Monday, August 15, 2011 8:00am (Eastern Standard Time)End:Monday, August 15, 2011 9:00am ";

    StringBuilder builderString = new StringBuilder(strTest);

    for (int i = 0; i < builderString.length(); i++) {


        if(builderString.charAt(i)==':'){

            if(Character.isDigit(builderString.charAt(i-1))){

                builderString.setCharAt(i, '-');

            }
        }


    }       
    strTest=builderString.toString();       

    System.out.println(strTest);
```

Comment: I know that but cant get by line to line